# Prove inequalities of two summation series

Tags: calculus

Prove :

$$\left[\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \cosh2x_k \right) \times \left(\sum_{k=1}^n (\sinh2x_k)(\tanh2x_k)\right)\right] \le 4 \left[ \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \cosh^2x_k\right) \times \sum_{k=1}^n \sinh^2x_k\right]$$

I have tried hyperbolic trig identities and I am not getting that the left hand side is less than or equal to the right hand side.  When I graph cosh 2x, sinh2xtan2x, sinh^2, cosh^2 it seems that left side should be greater than the right side.

Comment: If $n=1$, then the two sides are equal which is good.

Comment: You are right, the two sides are equal for n=1.  For n=2 though the left side is greater than the right side.